# Strange Python character encoding phenomenon

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, matplotlib

I have been trying to get matplotlib to correctly display the £/€ symbols as an axis label and have ended up finding something quite confusing that I was hoping someone here may be able to shed some light on.

If I type the following into my python console: `unicode('£','utf-8')`, I get this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: invalid start byte`.

However, if I execute a python script with this as my only line, I get the '£' symbol printed back to me (and this is ultimately how I ended up getting the '£' symbol into my plot).

```
print unicode('£','utf-8')
```

Any ideas? Thanks for any insight you may be able to give!

Ben

EDIT:

Two scripts and the output of each:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylabel( unicode( '£', 'utf-8' ) )
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output1]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylabel( u'£' )
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output2]

EDIT 2:

Adding `#coding: utf8` to my second example code doesn't change things:

```
#coding: utf8

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylabel( u'£' )
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output3]

Comment: I think this is because of your terminal app. What os do you use? Can you check in the settings that your terminal character encoding is UTF-8?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, and both in the console and script, the following returns 'cp1252': `import sys; sys.getdefaultencoding()`

Comment: I added that comment to the top of my script and it doesn't change anything. The script still works and the console doesn't.

Comment: Well, you can try `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`

Comment: @ForceBru the thing is, both console and script have the same default encoding (cp1252), so I wouldn't have thought that was causing the issue? When I try and do `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'`

Comment: @Ben you would need `reload(sys)`  before calling  setdefaultencoding but that is not a good way to go

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for your tip. I just tried that and it then does allow me to change the default encoding, but this line still doesn't work: `unicode('£','utf-8')`

Comment: Your shell is decoding the string  using cp1252 which is why you see `Â£`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So does this explain why `unicode( '£', 'utf-8' )` is working for my plot in the first example? But why then does it not work in my console?

Comment: where are you running each from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham both of the matplotlib examples are run from a script. So in a sense the first example was the solution to my original problem. However, I can't understand why this line `unicode( '£', 'utf-8' )` doesn't independently work in the console.

Comment: what does `unicode( '£', 'cp1252' )` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It outputs: `u'\xa3'` but if I do `print unicode( '£', 'cp1252' )` I get `Â£`

Comment: I mean when you print it, that is the repr output you are seeing

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah I realised immediately that's what you meant and edited my response at the same time as your reply!

Comment: `u'\xa3'`  is correct, `u'\xc2\xa3'` would be `Â£` . So when you use it matplotlib is it still displayed incorrectly?

Comment: Yes when I use `unicode( '£', 'cp1252' )` with matplotlib I get `Â£` (as do I when I `print unicode( '£', 'cp1252' )` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using unicode literals u'£'

Comment: I will edit my question to show the result of using this with a minimum working example matplotlib figure. For some reason using u'£' doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the encoding of your source file. Add this line at the top of your python script:

```
#coding: utf8
```

Info: [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: Adding this to my source file doesn't change anything to the examples above.

Comment: @Ben I think that's because your source file isn't actually UTF-8. Figure out which encoding your editor creates and use the same coding comment but with the proper encoding string. You might try `windows-1252` if you don't know.

Comment: @Ben looking at your examples again, I think the coding comment recommended in this answer should fix the second example. The UTF-8 representation of `£` when misinterpreted as cp1252 is `Â£`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried that - see Edit 2 of my post. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Ben you need to make sure that line is the first or second line of your file, if it's not it has no effect.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, this now produces just the '£' sign. It was the first line of my file, apart from the docstring, but I guess that was enough to stop it working. I'm still a bit confused by the fact that this line `unicode('£','utf-8')` works in a script but not in the console, despite them both using cp1252 encoding.

Comment: @Ben judging by the evidence your console is cp1252 but the script is UTF-8. What are you using as an editor for your script?

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm using a forked version of Spyder, but if I run `sys.getdefaultencoding()` I get `cp1252` in both the console and the editor.